# Programming: Minimum steps required to convert a binary number to zero

Tags: java, php, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was working on a programming exercise and was stuck on figuring out the correct algorithm. Here is the problem:

> Given a decimal number, how many minimum possible steps are required to convert this to zero provided:
>
> 1. Change the bit i if the next bit i+1 is '1' and all the other bits i+2 and later are 0
> 2. Change the last bit without restriction

For example:

if input is (8)Base10 = (1000)Base2, then the steps taken are:

```
1000→1001→1011→1010→1110→1111→1101→1100→0100→0101→0111→0110→0010→0011→0001→0000
```

total 15 steps are required.

Complete the following definition:

```
int minStepsRequired(long number)
```

It's ok to get a pseudo code or just the algorithm. This is not a homework or assignment.

Comment: Hi, roger_that, you also would like to post this as a puzzle in [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: And clarify your process, i.e. what is 'set' (= 1?) and 'rest' ?

Comment: @FernandoBravoDiaz already posted, see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/180220/minimum-steps-to-convert-a-binary-number-to-zero
 .I was told to post it here.

Comment: This seems more like a logic / math question, rather than a *specific, programming* one. Weird that they told you to post it here, unless my understanding of how SO works is flawed.

Comment: As per the comment on `codegolf`, it says `This might be a better fit for the stack overflow site`

Comment: @Fureeish The people there might thing StackOverflow is an automatic homework machine. Wouldn't blame them. Could fool anyone. :)

Comment: @roger_that Instead of believeing random people off the internet, you should read the site descriptions.

Comment: Did that. Can we get some help here with the algo?

Comment: Nope. You need to try it yourself first. Write some code and get back if you get stumped.

Comment: @roger_that Is `1.` and `2.` one step?

Comment: @TabmanRekoj: No, they are two different steps, can perform either of those.

Comment: This is a straightforward breadth-first search of a graph.  The nodes are the binary values; the edges are allowable moves from each node.  There are many examples on line of such searches.  Code your transitions, test your result.  Post here if you get *stuck*.

Comment: @roger_that Did you solve it or not? Can you post a link to a working solution?

Comment: @Developerium this question is tagged Java, not PHP. You need to post another question. But the algorithm is already available, why don't just implement it yourself?

Comment: @phuclv I'm having a hard time coming up with a clean solution, so that's why I offered a bounty. BTW I added the PHP tag, so feel free to post an answer and get that yummy bounty ;)

Comment: @Developerium Do you want just the number of steps or the complete list of steps?

Comment: @Olivier I'm looking for the recursive one, I can see the fast one here!

Answer (score 16):

This is a wonderful problem for a recursive algorithm.

If the length of the binary representation is 0, you can already tell the answer. Or if length 0 is not allowed, then if the length is 1 you tell the answer depending on whether that one bit is 0 or 1.

If the length is longer than 1:

- If the first bit is 0, the answer is the same as it would be without that 0 bit. Remove it and call recursively to get the answer.
- If the first bit is 1, divide into three subproblems and find the step count for each:

  1. Establish a situation where you are allowed to change the leading 1 to 0. This means it should be followed by a 1 and then all 0s. Write a recursive auxiliary algorithm for this. It is going to be quite similar to the main algorithm, and likely they can share some logic.
  2. Flip the 1 to 0 (1 step)
  3. Convert the remaining bits bits to 0. Another recursive call.

The algorithm may take a long time. It is actually counting the steps, so takes time proportional to the number of steps, which I think is roughly proportional to the input number. Your method takes a `long` argument, but with my algorithm for large `long` values it may not terminate witin the lifetime of the computer it is running on. Also the number of steps may overflow an `int` and even a `long` (if the input is a negative `long` value).

### The fast way

The following solution doesn’t require recursion and runs in constant time. I can’t explain properly how it works, which is a serious problem if we want to use it for something. I played with some examples, saw a pattern and generalized it. By contrast IMHO some of the beauty of the recursive solution above is that it is straightforward to understand (if you understand recursion).

Example: Input 8 or `1000` binary. Result 15 or `1111` binary. The pattern is: each bit of the result is the XOR of the previous bit of the result and the bit in the same position in the input. So from `1000` just copy the front bit, 1. The following bit is 1 XOR 0 = 1, where 1 is the front bit of the result and 0 is taken from the input. The remaining two bits are calculated the same way.

A longer example so you can check if you understood:

```
Input:  115 = 1110011
Result:       1011101 = 93
```

Or in code:

```
static BigInteger calculateStepsRequired(long number) {
    // Take sign bit
    int bit = number < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(bit);
    for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
        number = number << 1;
        int sign = number < 0 ? 1 : 0;
        bit = (bit + sign) % 2;
        result = result.shiftLeft(1).add(BigInteger.valueOf(bit));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have checked this method against my own implementation of the first algorithm above using various inputs up to 100 000 000, and they always agree, so I believe that the fast method is correct too. I still suggest that you should code, run and test it to verify that I got it right.

Comment: The actual question in the OP is "what's the index of this gray-code-number" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Gray_code_counters_and_arithmetic). And this is pretty much what the faster version in your code does.

Answer (score 12):

At first, I tried to solve it with a recursive depth-first function (in NodeJS) but it just worked for small numbers - an input value such as `10^5` would generate a runtime error due to the number of recursive calls in the stack.

So then I tried to see how I could reduce the problem to the sum of smaller problems and found out that the number of steps for N, being N a power of 2, was

### Rule #1

> N * 2 - 1

(e.g.: number of steps for 2 is 3, for 32 is 63, for 256 is 511, and so on).

Then I had find what to do with any other number (that is not a power of 2) and since any integer is the sum of different powers of 2 (hence the binary representation), I only had to see if the number of steps would add up as well ... but it was not the case. However, I did find that I had to not just add the number of steps from every power of two, but to

### Rule #2

> subtract and add the steps in an alternate fashion, starting from the highest order digit

## Demonstration

Given number **42** (`101010` in binary)

Let's first apply **Rule #1**

```
1 0 1 0 1 0
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
| | | | | |_           0 steps
| | | | |___  2*2-1 =  3 steps
| | | |_____           0 steps
| | |_______  2*8-1 = 15 steps
| |_________           0 steps
|___________ 2*32-1 = 63 steps
```

And secondly, applying **Rule #2**:

```
63 - 15 + 3 = 51
```

> The total number of steps is **51**

## Implementation (JavaScript)

```js
function minOperations(n) {
  const bin = n.toString(2);
  const digitCount = bin.length;
  let accumulator = 0;
  let sign = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < digitCount; ++i) {
    const digit = Number.parseInt(bin.charAt(i));
    const power = digit > 0 ? Math.pow(2, digitCount - (i + 1)) : 0;
    const steps = digit * (power * 2 - 1);

    accumulator += steps * sign;
    sign = sign * (digit == 0 ? 1 : -1);
  }
  
  return accumulator;
}
```

Comment: The reason this is happening is in each step you're basically negating the sign of the entire calculation. so instead of thinking about it like alternating between addition and subtraction, you can think of it as 63 - (15 - 3) = 51. Hence, as others pointed out, a great problem for a recursive solution.

Comment: as I mentioned at the beginning of my post, recursion didn't work for big numbers, hence the workaround explained here

Answer (score 10):

Here is a recursive PHP function for computing the number of steps required. It operates by noting there are two possible requirements:

1. convert a string to `0`s (the overall requirement); and
2. convert a string to a `1` followed by a string of `0`s (to allow flipping the preceding digit)

The second requirement is obviously an extension of the first, and so it's possible to write a recursive function which does both. It has a special case for the single digit length string, just checking if it needs to be flipped or not.

```
function reduce($bits, $value = '0') {
    if (strlen($bits) == 1) {
        // a single bit can be flipped as needed
        return ($bits[0] == $value) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    if ($bits[0] == $value) {
        // nothing to do with this bit, flip the remainder
        return reduce(substr($bits, 1));
    }
    // need to convert balance of string to 1 followed by 0's 
    // then we can flip this bit, and then reduce the new string to 0
    return reduce(substr($bits, 1), '1') + 1 + reduce(str_pad('1', strlen($bits) - 1, '0'));
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/colSe)

This function can be adapted to store the actual steps taken, then the number of steps is just the count of that array (-1, since we put the original value in the array too). To store the steps we need to keep track of the first part of the string (`$prefix` in the below code) as well as the part we are reducing:

```
function reduce($bits, $prefix, $value = '0') {
    if (strlen($bits) == 1) {
        // a single bit can be flipped as needed
        return array($prefix . ($bits[0] == '0' ? '1' : '0'));
    }
    if ($bits[0] == $value) {
        // nothing to do with this bit, flip the remainder
        $prefix .= $bits[0];
        return reduce(substr($bits, 1), $prefix);
    }
    // need to convert balance of string to 1 followed by 0's 
    $prefix .= $bits[0];
    $steps = reduce(substr($bits, 1), $prefix, '1');
    // now we can flip this bit
    $prefix = substr($prefix, 0, -1) . ($bits[0] == '0' ? '1' : '0');
    $steps[] = $prefix . str_pad('1', strlen($bits) - 1, '0');
    // now reduce the new string to 0
    $steps = array_merge($steps, reduce(str_pad('1', strlen($bits) - 1, '0'), $prefix));
    return $steps;
}
```

You can run this like so:

```
$bin = decbin($i);
$steps = array_merge(array($bin), reduce($bin, ''));
echo "$i ($bin) takes " . (count($steps) - 1) . " steps\n";
print_r($steps);
```

Output for an input of 8:

```
8 (1000) takes 15 steps
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 1001
    [2] => 1011
    [3] => 1010
    [4] => 1110
    [5] => 1111
    [6] => 1101
    [7] => 1100
    [8] => 0100
    [9] => 0101
    [10] => 0111
    [11] => 0110
    [12] => 0010
    [13] => 0011
    [14] => 0001
    [15] => 0000
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TJZuB)

**Gray code**

Looking at the steps we can see that this is actually a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) (Reflected Binary Code) counting from the original value down to 0. So if we generate a list of sufficient codes to cover the starting value, we can simply look for the binary representation of the starting value in that list, and that will give us the number of steps required to get back to 0:

```
function gray_code($bits) {
    if ($bits == 1) {
        return array('0', '1');
    }
    else {
        $codes = gray_code($bits - 1);
        return array_merge(array_map(function ($v) { return '0' . $v; }, $codes),
                           array_map(function ($v) { return '1' . $v; }, array_reverse($codes))
        );
    }
}

$value = 8;
$bin = decbin($value);
// get sufficient gray codes to cover the input
$gray_codes = gray_code(strlen($bin));
$codes = array_flip($gray_codes);
echo "$bin takes {$codes[$bin]} steps to reduce to 0\n";
// echo the steps
for ($i = $codes[$bin]; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo $gray_codes[$i] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9I40K)

If you don't need the individual steps you can just use a Gray code to binary converter to find the number of steps. This is super fast:

```
function gray_to_binary($value) {
    $dec = $value;
    for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
        $dec[$i] = (int)$dec[$i-1] ^ (int)$value[$i];
    }
    return $dec;
}

echo bindec(gray_to_binary(decbin(115)));
```

Output:

```
93
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/c1k1H)

**A Gray Code Generator**

We can use an iterative Gray code generator to count down the steps from our original code. The advantage of this is that it doesn't consume any memory to store the codes so it can work for very large numbers. This version uses a Gray code to binary converter that works with integers rather than strings as did the one above:

```
function gray_to_binary($value) {
    $dec = 0;
    $bits = floor(log($value, 2));
    for ($i = $bits; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $dec = $dec | (((($dec >> ($i + 1)) ^ ($value >> $i)) & 1) << $i);
    }
    return $dec;
}

function iterate_gray($value) {
    // get the equivalent starting binary value
    $code = decbin($value);
    yield $code;
    $len = strlen($code);
    $count = gray_to_binary($value);
    while ($count > 0) {
        // flip the bit which corresponds to the least significant 1 bit in $count
        $xor = 1;
        while (($count & $xor) == 0) $xor <<= 1;
        $value ^= $xor;
        yield sprintf("%0{$len}b", $value);
        $count--;
    }
}

foreach (iterate_gray(8) as $code) {
    echo $code . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
1000
1001
1011
1010
1110
1111
1101
1100
0100
0101
0111
0110
0010
0011
0001
0000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aSJJh)

Comment: Great answer. I had also found the connection with Gray Code thanks to [this site](https://oeis.org/A006068) (you give it the beginning of a sequence and it tells you what it is).

Comment: @Olivier thanks. I started life as an EE and had to design one of these for an asynchronous interface so recognised the pattern once I started writing the code. That site you gave a link to looks really useful thanks - I will add it to my reference list.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a PHP implementation of Ole's "fast way" algorithm. The idea is the same:

- Initialize the result with the first bit of the number (starting from the left)
- For every following bit of the number, XOR it with the previous bit of the result, which gives a new bit for the result

```php
function getBit($number, $i)
{
    // Extracts bit i from number
    return ($number & (1<<$i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}

function minStepsRequired($number)
{
    $i = 30; // Enough to handle all positive 32-bit integers
    $bit = getBit($number, $i); // First bit
    $res = $bit;
    do
    {
        $i--;
        $bit ^= getBit($number, $i); // Computes XOR between previous bit of the result and current bit of the number
        $res = ($res<<1) + $bit; // Shifts the result to the left by 1 position and adds the new bit
    }
    while($i>0);
    return $res;
}

var_dump(minStepsRequired(8)); // Outputs 15
var_dump(minStepsRequired(115)); // Outputs 93
```

Comment: Could you please explain the steps?

Comment: @Developerium I have added some more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to notice that the first k bits, which are zeroes can be left as they are and you only start with the (k + 1)'th bit and we ignore all the starting bits, having a value of zero and always aim to increase their number. This is our primary goal and thus, we always reduce the problem-space to a similar, but smaller problem-space. Now, assuming that your number looks like

**1**b1b2b3...bn

you need to make sure that b1 is 1 and b2, b3, ..., bn is 0 in order to be able to modify the bit prior to b1 to 0. After that happened, you know that b2 is 1 and all the subsequent bits are 0, then the new goal is to change b2 to 0, knowing that all the subsequent bits are 0.

You can keep track of your progress with a stack which can have as much elements as many bits you are working with, always its top will represent your current goal.

So, when you want to zero your first bit, then achieving the right sequence of subsequent bits represent subtasks for you before you can change your bit and once you succeeded doing so, you need to proceed similarly, but ignoring the first bit. You can number the steps.

Assuming that a number of

1...0000000

can be zeroed in 2^n - 1 steps, the total number of steps to do equals with 2^n - 1 + the number of steps needed to achieve the combination we see above. I didn't check whether it's 2^n - 1 though

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int reduce(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = ch.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (i == 0 && ch[i] == '0') {
            return count - 1;
        }

        if (i == 0 && ch[i] == '1') {
            return count + 1;
        }

        if (ch[i] == '0') {
            count++;
        } else {
            count++;
            ch[i] = '0';
            i++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def minOperations(n):
    number = []
    while n>0:
        number.append(n%2)
        n = n // 2

    ans = 0
    sign = 1
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if number[i] == 1:
            ans = (2**(i+1) - 1) - ans
    return ans
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.